# How to specify shema while creating dataframe from socket sourced data?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, streaming

I am fairly new to spark. I am streaming the log files in following format on port `9999` -

```
2019-09-15 23:45:37,370|10.1.198.43|splunk|headObject|splunk|splunk|160|0|55|246|461|1322|_introspection%2Fdma%2F27%2F99%2F103%7E955F0453-052A-4B49-BC09-8259A2B608E4%2F5C218CC9-77D3-4BBE-AD24-A5FB31CC56F2_DM_SplunkforPaloAltoNetworks_pan_wildfire_report%2Freceipt.json|404|2d86e6fa-c7e4-1c5b-8d12-54ab3a911327|0|NoSuchKey|
2019-09-15 23:45:37,379|10.1.198.53|splunk|getObject|splunk|splunk|160|0|55|246|461|1567|_introspection%2Fdma%2F27%2F99%2F103%7E955F0453-052A-4B49-BC09-8259A2B608E4%2F5C218CC9-77D3-4BBE-AD24-A5FB31CC56F2_DM_SplunkforPaloAltoNetworks_pan_wildfire_report%2Freceipt.json|404|2d86e6fc-c7e4-1c5b-8d12-54ab3a911327|0|NoSuchKey|
2019-09-15 23:45:37,430|10.1.198.53|splunk|headObject|splunk|splunk|160|0|55|246|461|1329|_introspection%2Fdma%2F27%2F99%2F103%7E955F0453-052A-4B49-BC09-8259A2B608E4%2F5C218CC9-77D3-4BBE-AD24-A5FB31CC56F2_DM_SplunkforPaloAltoNetworks_pan_wildfire_report%2Freceipt.json|404|2d86e6fe-c7e4-1c5b-8d12-54ab3a911327|0|NoSuchKey|
2019-09-15 23:45:38,545|10.29.2.5||unknown|||0|0|0|250|250|223||400|2d86e700-c7e4-1c5b-8d12-54ab3a911327|0|InvalidBucketName|
2019-09-15 23:45:38,614|10.29.2.6||unknown|||0|0|0|250|250|187||400|2d86e702-c7e4-1c5b-8d12-54ab3a911327|0|InvalidBucketName|
```

And my streaming coding that given me a dataframe is -

```scala
val linesDF: DataFrame = spark
      .readStream
      .format("socket")
      .option("host", "127.0.0.1")
      .option("port", 9999)
      .option("delimiter", "|")
      .schema(schema1)
      .load()
```

But I am getting an error that I can not specify schema with `socket` source. How to read this data?

My schema looks like this -

```scala
val schemaString = "dttm|ip|bktownr|oper|bktnm|usr|" +
      "reqhdr|reqbd|reshdr|resbd|totsize|" +
      "duration|objnm|httpstts|s3reqid|etag|errcd|srcbkt"

    val schema1 = StructType(
      schemaString
        .split('|')
        .map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true))
    )
```

After removing the option, I know I can read the data but its read under single column called `value`. I performed experiments on loading the data into static dataframe and provide schema there. But that is not working in this case where I actually want to convert the process into streaming where data will be streamed over socket `9999`.

Is there any other way I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to read the logs in the structured streaming fashion of spark, you can directly specify the log file directory and spark will read it in a stream along with new files as well. Here is how I solved this issue -

```
val rawData = spark
      .readStream
      .format("csv")
      .option("delimiter", "|")
      .option("header", "true")
      .schema(customSchema)
      .load("/Users/username/logs/cloud-logs")
```